# How to reduce tree nodes by property?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I tried to reduce tree where `visible = true or undefined`:

[Link to demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAJghmMQLwQN4EsoC4IEYA0EAxgBZrBQBOIAdtgNooCwAUBGxBtvhNTALYhsAIgCCQggDc0AZzQAjUNgBmMYNJAsAvnhYsmrdpwgAmArwHCAQuIhTZCwRDAUAriAIkylGvXRYIACxm-I5CACI2dvKKECpqIJoAulo6zHos7Bz+AMzBFhBCAMKRMtGOcepausyJmgDc1dVKLtSEYGgA9tQQVFAuhCAAFNQdUI4w1ACeAJTYE5OoGYZKgwCEI2MQAD5bEOujIAD8AHSe5FTU0z3gLhTdGyANBmwPp6TnNEg8B29eF8dKMhgEAUQaDM7+eZXRAAPiI7ygJyiDiQiGQLTGgOoICg212EOOyNAqOQzjc0yeSzYSg6oNAkDQSAADBA6mgADyIV4Q-6gagAczAxDqHAA1KKrvpMplev0htyERc6GhEhSqRBNNUZTc7t8xpTmJq0sxCF1pB1QMdgB1+YNZQNBrB4NM1cagA)

```
function reduce(node: any): any {
    if(!node || !node?.children) return;
    node.children = node.children.filter((child: any) => child?.visible === undefined || child.visible === true);

    for(let i =0 ;i<=node.children.length; i++) {
        reduce(node.children[i]);
    }

    return node;

}

console.log(reduce(data));
```

So, I `filter` each children array of element but I can not get how to return this modified array?

Inside `node.children` I get mapped element, then I need go through each elements deeper.

Comment: What you want to achieve after all?

Comment: I want to get result tree where visible = true or not exist

Comment: Can you be more specific about what the output is? An array of objects whose children have the visible property true? I can't figure it out

Comment: The same structure excluding nodes where visible = false

Comment: Have you considered using filter?

Comment: Yes, I use it check this out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree it's not easy to get it right at a first try, and I must say that you almost got it right. It turns out that there are many approaches to solve your problem, but personally, I like to structure the algorithm's logic based on induction in order to make the steps cleaner.

##### Goal

Here you can determine what you want. From what I got from you, it's needed to go through each node of a tree of structure and filter the ones that have visible attribute equals to `true`.

```
{
  id: number, 
  name: string, 
  visible: boolean, 
  children?: node[]
}
```

##### Strong Induction on number of children

1. Base case:
   a) when the input is falsy [full list here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) return an empty tree.
   b) when it has no `children` attribute, check if it is visible and in case it is return the tree.
2. Induction Hypothesis: Assume you **know** how to solve the problem for any tree with `k` children (k integer, 0 <= k < n).
3. General Case: Prove that you can solve for a tree with `n` children (n integer).

##### Idea of solution

Input: Tree of n children

1. Use the *base case* if-checking description to create first lines.
2. Pass through each children of tree and check if it has the property `visible` set to `true`.
3. Apply the *induction hyphotesis* on them (because they are who have less than n nodes).
4. Push each partial solution to a new array (*general case*).
5. Replace the original array of children of the one got previously.

##### Pseudocode

```
algorithm reduce
   input: tree with n children
   output: same tree filtered under conditions

 if input is not a tree then 
    return an empty tree
 else if input has no children attribute and its visible attribute is true then
    return the input tree
 else 
    filteredChildren := new empty Array
    for each node in tree do
       if node visible attribute is true then
           ans := reduce(node)   -- Induction Hypothesis
           filteredChildren.append(ans)
    tree.children = filteredChildren
    return tree
```

##### Typescript algorithm

As seen in [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAJghmMQLwQN4FgBQFsQJZQC4IBGAGggDdcBnXAI1CIDMZhqRyBjAC12CgBOIAHZEA2uiw5p%20ImQjCYAWxBEARAEE15KrQaqILNiEzSAvqUymck6TMIQATOUUr1AIW2Ua9RhDACAK4cEDx8giLiKHgOACwuygZqACJeur4GRuwQZgC61tgWVlLYtnbYshAAzAluEGoAwmk%20%20sys7AU5mGbFoJCw8I5IqJ2V8q5JWjotflkhYfxCohBindJl5fZytZPNerPtJiV2Rcfra5uVzgqJHnsZRAHBXLyLkSsXmzafX3aVNTc6o17q1DIcXuEluIfr9NhtYQithB4oCkqlpvsDE95q8IssxPkzojNj0icSIITyYVLGTfvCqTEiABWHbqACiIIOxhhJJpDPpVMqADZWfUAGKcrFBHGQ94EnnlU78hW-SoAdlFagA4pLHtKVeY%20QjKSTOoSzABuYqYJiBYScMC4AD2wggQiggU4IAAFAEQAYYMIAJ4ASiIgaDI2OuCYEG9AEI-SAQ27wIEBK6UJbRrGE0mAHQLPEpoRgdOugvpfRIRDIbEQAD8-iEIAgRCzVuOBaLS2G3dxS3zTD4YBAAm93qL4eDKcQAD5Qrj81XQDW69KQz980oYAAHCdTiAR2cL92en1FkOb46l8vN-2d0mYTgu6hO0D54BOgDm3rPXu9AYYCvTsX2EN8Py-X9-x9IDHBA4ogA), check it with your input.

```js
function reduce(tree: any): any {
    if (!tree) return {};
    if (!tree.children) return tree.visible === true ? tree : {};
    tree.children = tree.children.filter((child: any) => child.visible === true)
                                 .map((child: any) => reduce(child))
    return tree;
}
```